# Why javascript GainNode not works properly in Safari?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

Does anyone have any idea why changing volume on Audio with `AudioContext` `GainNode` does not work properly in Safari? Both, Mac OS and iOS seems to behave similar.

Try [this example](https://mdn.github.io/webaudio-examples/media-source-buffer/) on MDN or [my example](https://codepen.io/Tomas-Javurek/pen/xxymMmz) on CodePen. Both works well on Chrome but on Safari does not.

Cannot find any solution on the web.

Comment: Maybe this will [help](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/47520)

Comment: it seems the above example on codepen works well with local audio media..., not with live broadcast :(